# Загружается ли контент который невостребованный?

Tags: html, css, оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

Вопрос из теоретической области CSS. Я на многих ресурсах читал, что для ускорения скорости отображения странниц минимизируют количество файлов с css подгружаемых к проекту. (Речь о крупных проекта, а не лендингах, пример интернет магазины) В примерах приводилось два файла. В первом хранятся библиотечные стили во втором стили разработчика. 
В файле со стилями разработчика включены все используемые стили на всех страницах + их адаптивный вариант. А теперь вопросы - 
будет ли эти запрос к серверу каждый раз на получение картинок прописанных через background-image от тех классов которых нету в разметке HTML ? 
А если эти классы будут добавляться в DOM дерево посредством JS. ? Пойдет ли запрос

Comment: Изображения, загружаемые через css в качестве бэкгрунда, кэшируются браузером. Загружаются файлы css, там хоть 1 стиль использоваться будет, не важно, загрузится файл целиком. Если это вас так беспокоит, используйте кэширование на своем сайте.

Comment: я вообще-то понял вопрос так: загружаются ли картинки из ссылок background-image, которые отсутствуют в документе ит.д. Мне кажется, вы на более очевидный ответили :)

Comment: Нет, невостребованные background-image не загружаются. Вы можете это проверить в development tools->network

Comment: А если классы через JS добавляются, но они уже объявлены в стилях, и там прописаны ссылки на изображения? когда пойдет запрос к серверу? ПС Допустив найхудший вариант и в файле .htaccess как и на хостинге забыли прописать кэширование файлов

Comment: @BlackStar1991 да какая разница. Кеширование ни при чем. Если в разметке html нет background-image, то никак не загрузится. Браузер не дурнее паровоза.